# Android connect bridge for Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, android, connection

I have a Marshmallow based Android smart phone. Most PC suites won't work on Ubuntu. Is there any integration possible between Ubuntu and Android.

I heard about *KDE Connect* which connects Android to Ubuntu. I am not sure whether it will work since I am using stock Ubuntu + Unity, not KDE Plasma.

Is there any trusted tool ( I have privacy concerns ) which can link an Android Smart Phone with Ubuntu ? Thanks.

PS : I prefer using a WiFi network for the integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may install KDE Connect from a PPA in Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity. Open terminal and run these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:varlesh-l/indicator-kdeconnect
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install kdeconnect indicator-kdeconnect
```

You can install KDE Connect app on android from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp) or [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.kde.kdeconnect_tp/).

### [Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/kde-connect-indicator-ubuntu)

Comment: Will it work on Unity ?

Comment: Apparently yes. See the linked article.

Comment: Thanks. I have privacy concerns as well. What do you think of KDE connect ?

Comment: You might want to see [this](https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/kdeconnect/2014-June/000195.html).